# Order By - LINQ to Lambda

Tags: linq, lambda

How would you represent this LINQ `Order By` statement using a Lambda expression?

```
OrderBy price.Quantity <= 50 ? price.Quantity : -price.Quantity
```

Comment: Don't think anyone understands what you mean.What you wrote does not make sense.What do you want to do?

Comment: Do you mean using the Lambda syntax method of Linq?

Comment: Did you try putting it in the `OrderBy()` method?... `Prices.OrderBy(price => price.Quantity <= 50 ? price.Quantity : -price.Quantity)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean the Lambda syntax method of Linq, you can do

```
var ordered = myQuery.OrderBy(p => p.Quantity <= 50? p.Quantity : -p.Quantity);
```

Note that you can express complex conditions like

```
var ordered = myQuery.OrderBy(p => 
    {
        if (somethingComplex)
        {
            return somethingCalculated;
        }
        else return somethingElseCalculated;
    });
```

If you execute your OrderBy against Linq-to-Entities, the lambda needs to be translatable to a store expression. If it cannot be translated to a store expression, you can use [.AsEnumerable()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb335435%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to cause the OrderBy to be executed client-side instead.

Comment: It is being used against Linq-to-Entities. I will have to read up on a `store expression`.

Comment: Your particular case works fine against Linq-to-Entities. However, if you use something that cannot be expressed in SQL (or that the current provider doesn't translate to something in SQL), you would get a runtime error. Example: `.OrderBy(p => MyCSharpFunction(p))`